# How to validate routing url in codeigniter with two parameters?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem with codeigniter 3

in my file routes.php I have

```
$route['article/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'article/index/$1/$2';
```

in my file article.php I have

```
<?php
```

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Article extends Frontend_Controller {

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->data['recent_news'] = $this->article_m->get_recent();
}

public function index($id, $slug)
{
    // Fetch the article
    $this->article_m->set_published();
    $this->data['article'] = $this->article_m->get($id);

    // Return 404 if not found uri_string() return blog/comments/123
    count($this->data['article']) || show_404(uri_string());

    // Redirect if slug was incorrect
    $request_slug = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $set_slug = $this->data['article']->slug;
    if ($request_slug != $set_slug) {
        // with 301 redirect
        redirect('article/' . $this->data['article']->id . '/' . $this->data['article']->slug, 'location', 301);
    }
    // Load view
    add_meta_title($this->data['article']->title);
    $this->data['subview'] = 'article';
    $this->load->view('_main_layout', $this->data);
}
```

}

when I enter to the url http://ci-cms.com/article/6/confesion
it's ok, but if I enter to the url http://ci-cms.com/article
I have a problem as this:

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
```

Type: ArgumentCountError

Message: Too few arguments to function Article::index(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\ci-cms\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 532 and exactly 2 expected

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\ci-cms\application\controllers\article.php

Line Number: 12

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ci-cms\index.php
Line: 320
Function: require_once

How can I resolve this problem?, please help me I'm new in this framework...

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What is it you are expecting to happen?  Going to http://ci-cms.com/article should go to the index method.  The error is stating that you are missing the $id and $slug parameters.

You could do something like this:

```
public function index($id = NULL, $slug = NULL)
{
```

But you would then need to add code to check to make sure that $id and $slug are not null.

Like this:

```
public function index($id = NULL, $slug = NULL)
{
    if (!is_null($id) && !is_null($slug))
    {
        // Fetch the article
        $this->article_m->set_published();
        $this->data['article'] = $this->article_m->get($id);

        // Return 404 if not found uri_string() return blog/comments/123
        count($this->data['article']) || show_404(uri_string());

        // Redirect if slug was incorrect
        $request_slug = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $set_slug = $this->data['article']->slug;
        if ($request_slug != $set_slug)
        {
            // with 301 redirect
            redirect('article/' . $this->data['article']->id . '/' . $this->data['article']->slug, 'location', 301);
        }
        // Load view
        add_meta_title($this->data['article']->title);
        $this->data['subview'] = 'article';
        $this->load->view('_main_layout', $this->data);
    }
}
```

Comment: If this answered your question please mark this as answered. Thanks.